# Bootstrap Accordions expanding, but not collapsing?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I am having trouble with a bootstrap 5 accordion. They all expand without issue but won't collapse back down. I don't know if my JS or CSS is causing an issue. I don't see any errors in Chrome's console.

https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/whoward-dev-area/df.php

I copied them into codepen and didn't have any issues.

```html
                  <h2>Important Dates (Fall 2022)</h2>
                  <div class="accordion">
                     <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                           <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e639">
                                 16-Week Classes (August 22 - December 16)</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_d15e639" class="accordion-body collapse">
                           <div class="accordion-inner">
                              <div class="harperTable">
                                 <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td><span>April 18-20, 2022</span></td>
                                          <td><span>Fall priority registration begins</span></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td><span>April 21, 2022</span></td>
                                          <td><span>Open registration for Fall 2022 for all students.</span></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>August 22, 2022</td>
                                          <td>16-week classes begin this week</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>August 29, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Last day to drop for 100% refund for 16-week classes</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>September 5, 2022</td>
                                          <td>College closed in observance of Labor Day</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>September 7, 2022</td>
                                          <td>First Financial Aid Disbursement</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>November 8, 2022</td>
                                          <td>College closed in observance of General Election Day</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>November 21, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Last day to withdraw from 16-week classes</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>November 23-27, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Thanksgiving Break</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>December 12-16, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Final Exam Week</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>December 21, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Grades available online</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="accordion">
                     <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                           <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e685">
                                 First 8-Week Classes (August 22 - October 16)</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_d15e685" class="accordion-body collapse">
                           <div class="accordion-inner">
                              <div class="harperTable">
                                 <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td><span>April 18-20, 2022</span></td>
                                          <td><span>Fall priority registration begins</span></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td><span>April 21, 2022</span></td>
                                          <td><span>Open registration for Fall 2022 for all students.</span></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>August 22, 2022</td>
                                          <td>First 8-week classes begin this week</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>August 29, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Last day to drop for 100% refund for first 8-week classes</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>September 5, 2022</td>
                                          <td>College closed in observance of Labor Day</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>September 7, 2022</td>
                                          <td>First Financial Aid Disbursement</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>October 3, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Last day to withdraw from first 8-week classes</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>October 16, 2022</td>
                                          <td>First 8-week classes end</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="accordion">
                     <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                           <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e722">
                                 Second 8-Week Classes (October 17 - December 11)</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_d15e722" class="accordion-body collapse">
                           <div class="accordion-inner">
                              <div class="harperTable">
                                 <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td><span>April 18-20, 2022</span></td>
                                          <td><span>Fall priority registration begins</span></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td><span>April 21, 2022</span></td>
                                          <td><span>Open registration for Fall 2022 for all students.</span></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>October 17, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Second 8-week classes begin this week</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>October 24, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Last day to drop for 100% refund for second 8-week classes.</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>November 8, 2022</td>
                                          <td>College closed in observance of General Election Day</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>November 23-27, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Thanksgiving Break</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>November 28, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Last day to withdraw from second 8-week classes.</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>December 11, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Second 8-week term ends</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="accordion">
                     <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                           <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e759">
                                 First 13-week Classes (August 22 - November 20)</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_d15e759" class="accordion-body collapse">
                           <div class="accordion-inner">
                              <div class="harperTable">
                                 <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td><span>April 18-20, 2022</span></td>
                                          <td><span>Fall priority registration begins</span></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td><span>April 21, 2022</span></td>
                                          <td><span>Open registration for Fall 2022 for all students.</span></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>August 22, 2022</td>
                                          <td>First 13-week classes begin this week</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>August 29, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Last day to drop for 100% refund for first 13-week classes</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>September 5, 2022</td>
                                          <td>College closed in observance of Labor Day</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>September 7, 2022</td>
                                          <td>First Financial Aid Disbursement</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>November 8, 2022</td>
                                          <td>College closed in observance of General Election Day</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>October 31, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Last day to withdraw from first 13-week classes</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>November 22, 2022</td>
                                          <td>First 13-week classes end.</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="accordion">
                     <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                           <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e799">
                                 Second 13-week Classes (September 19 - December 16)</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_d15e799" class="accordion-body collapse">
                           <div class="accordion-inner">
                              <div class="harperTable">
                                 <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td><span>April 18-20, 2022</span></td>
                                          <td><span>Fall priority registration begins</span></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td><span>April 21, 2022</span></td>
                                          <td><span>Open registration for Fall 2022 for all students.</span></td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>September 19, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Second 13-week classes begin this week</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>September 26, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Last day to drop for 100% refund for second 13-week classes</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>November 8, 2022</td>
                                          <td>College closed in observance of General Election Day</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>November 23-27, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Thanksgiving Break</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>November 28, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Last day to withdraw from second 13-week classes</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>December 16, 2022</td>
                                          <td>Second 13-week classes end.</td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="accordion">
                     <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                           <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e836">
                                 Important Dates for All Parts of Term</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_d15e836" class="accordion-body collapse">
                           <div class="accordion-inner">
                              <p><a href="https://www.harpercollege.edu/registration/pdf/web_dates_04192022.pdf">Fall 2022 Important Dates for All Parts of Term (pdf)</a></p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="accordion">
                     <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                           <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e846">
                                 Final Examination Schedule</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_d15e846" class="accordion-body collapse">
                           <div class="accordion-inner">
                              <p><a href="https://www.harpercollege.edu/registration/pdf/finalexamschedule_fall_2022.pdf">Final Examination Schedule Fall 2022 (pdf)</a></p>
                           </div>
                        </div><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></div>
```

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: The code you posted to the question works as expected, but the code on website does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this code now. It's working fine now. You have missed a parent id and attribute data-bs-parent="#accordionExample".

```
<h2>Important Dates (Fall 2022)</h2>
<div class="accordion-content" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e639">
                        16-Week Classes (August 22 - December 16)</a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_d15e639" class="accordion-body collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <div class="harperTable">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>April 18-20, 2022</span></td>
                                    <td><span>Fall priority registration begins</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>April 21, 2022</span></td>
                                    <td><span>Open registration for Fall 2022 for all students.</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>August 22, 2022</td>
                                    <td>16-week classes begin this week</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>August 29, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Last day to drop for 100% refund for 16-week classes</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>September 5, 2022</td>
                                    <td>College closed in observance of Labor Day</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>September 7, 2022</td>
                                    <td>First Financial Aid Disbursement</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>November 8, 2022</td>
                                    <td>College closed in observance of General Election Day</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>November 21, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Last day to withdraw from 16-week classes</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>November 23-27, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Thanksgiving Break</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>December 12-16, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Final Exam Week</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>December 21, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Grades available online</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e685">
                        First 8-Week Classes (August 22 - October 16)</a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_d15e685" class="accordion-body collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <div class="harperTable">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>April 18-20, 2022</span></td>
                                    <td><span>Fall priority registration begins</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>April 21, 2022</span></td>
                                    <td><span>Open registration for Fall 2022 for all students.</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>August 22, 2022</td>
                                    <td>First 8-week classes begin this week</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>August 29, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Last day to drop for 100% refund for first 8-week classes</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>September 5, 2022</td>
                                    <td>College closed in observance of Labor Day</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>September 7, 2022</td>
                                    <td>First Financial Aid Disbursement</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>October 3, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Last day to withdraw from first 8-week classes</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>October 16, 2022</td>
                                    <td>First 8-week classes end</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e722">
                        Second 8-Week Classes (October 17 - December 11)</a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_d15e722" class="accordion-body collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <div class="harperTable">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>April 18-20, 2022</span></td>
                                    <td><span>Fall priority registration begins</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>April 21, 2022</span></td>
                                    <td><span>Open registration for Fall 2022 for all students.</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>October 17, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Second 8-week classes begin this week</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>October 24, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Last day to drop for 100% refund for second 8-week classes.</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>November 8, 2022</td>
                                    <td>College closed in observance of General Election Day</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>November 23-27, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Thanksgiving Break</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>November 28, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Last day to withdraw from second 8-week classes.</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>December 11, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Second 8-week term ends</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e759">
                        First 13-week Classes (August 22 - November 20)</a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_d15e759" class="accordion-body collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <div class="harperTable">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>April 18-20, 2022</span></td>
                                    <td><span>Fall priority registration begins</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>April 21, 2022</span></td>
                                    <td><span>Open registration for Fall 2022 for all students.</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>August 22, 2022</td>
                                    <td>First 13-week classes begin this week</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>August 29, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Last day to drop for 100% refund for first 13-week classes</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>September 5, 2022</td>
                                    <td>College closed in observance of Labor Day</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>September 7, 2022</td>
                                    <td>First Financial Aid Disbursement</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>November 8, 2022</td>
                                    <td>College closed in observance of General Election Day</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>October 31, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Last day to withdraw from first 13-week classes</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>November 22, 2022</td>
                                    <td>First 13-week classes end.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e799">
                        Second 13-week Classes (September 19 - December 16)</a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_d15e799" class="accordion-body collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <div class="harperTable">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>April 18-20, 2022</span></td>
                                    <td><span>Fall priority registration begins</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span>April 21, 2022</span></td>
                                    <td><span>Open registration for Fall 2022 for all students.</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>September 19, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Second 13-week classes begin this week</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>September 26, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Last day to drop for 100% refund for second 13-week classes</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>November 8, 2022</td>
                                    <td>College closed in observance of General Election Day</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>November 23-27, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Thanksgiving Break</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>November 28, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Last day to withdraw from second 13-week classes</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>December 16, 2022</td>
                                    <td>Second 13-week classes end.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e836">
                        Important Dates for All Parts of Term</a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_d15e836" class="accordion-body collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <p><a href="https://www.harpercollege.edu/registration/pdf/web_dates_04192022.pdf">Fall 2022
                            Important Dates for All Parts of Term (pdf)</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-alt-1">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        aria-expanded="false" href="#collapse_d15e846">
                        Final Examination Schedule</a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse_d15e846" class="accordion-body collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <p><a href="https://www.harpercollege.edu/registration/pdf/finalexamschedule_fall_2022.pdf">Final
                            Examination Schedule Fall 2022 (pdf)</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using Bootstrap accordion, I use the following structure that works quite well.  It opens the panel clicked on and closes any other that may already be open.

## CSS

```
.FAQ {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.FAQcard {
    margin: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.FAQtitle {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 150%;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}

.FAQtitle::after {
    content: " ";
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-right: 1px solid #4a6e78;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4a6e78;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.FAQtitle.active::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.FAQpanel {
    background: #f1f2f3;
    color: #000;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2em;
    text-align: left;
}

.FAQpanel p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

## HTML

```
        <div class="FAQ">
            <div class="FAQcard">
                <div class="FAQtitle">Test Panel 1</div>
                <div class="FAQpanel fs-5">
                     Test text for panel 1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="FAQcard">
                <div class="FAQtitle">Test Panel 2</div>
                <div class="FAQpanel fs-5">
                     Test text for panel 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript inside the (document).ready() function:

```
            $(".FAQtitle").click(function (j) {
                var dropDown = $(this).closest(".FAQcard").find(".FAQpanel");
                $(this).closest(".FAQ").find(".FAQpanel").not(dropDown).slideUp();
                if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                    $(this).removeClass("active").removeClass("selected");
                } else {
                    $(this).closest(".FAQ").find(".FAQtitle.active").removeClass("active").removeClass("selected");
                    $(this).addClass("active selected");
                }
                dropDown.stop(false, true).slideToggle();
                j.preventDefault();
            });
```

Hopefully this is helpful for you!